# Can I modify a public function in base class to public slots in derived class in Qt?

Tags: qt, slot

I'm using Qt now.

I've written a C++ class **A** and there are some public functions in it. And now, I'm writing a Qt class **B** which has multiple inheritences from both **QObject** and **A**.

And I want to change one **public** function in **A** to **public slots** in **B**.

Can it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by simply creating a slot in `B` and delegating to `A`'s function in there.
Here's an example:

```
#include <QtCore>

class A {
    public:
        A() {}
        void foo() { qDebug() << "In A::foo()"; }
};

class B: public QObject, public A {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        B(QObject *parent=0): QObject(parent), A() {
            connect(this, SIGNAL(fire()), this, SLOT(foo()));
        }
    public slots:
        void foo() {
            qDebug() << "In slot B::foo()";
            A::foo();
        }
    signals:
        void fire();
    public:
        void test() { emit fire(); }
};
```

Class `A` doesn't need to be "aware" of Qt at all.

Comment: It is definitely the effect I want. But does it have a more direct way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think so. Either `A` has a slot or it doesn't. If it doesn't, you'll need to call it through/delegate from `B` somehow. For that, `B` needs a slot. You can't use `using`-directives in `slots` sections, so I don't see how you could bypass a member function in B. (Short of modifying the `moc` output.)